# Why AngularJS service factory is returning undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am having a service as follows

services.js

```
    var CalculatorService = angular.module('CalculatorService', [])

   CalculatorService.service('Calculator', function () {
      this.square = function (a) { return a*a};

   });
    CalculatorService.factory('StringManipulation', function () {

     var r=  function reverse(s) {
    var o = '';
    for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        o += s[i];
    return o;
   }

 return
 {
   reverseString: function reverseString(name)
   {
       return r(name);
   }
 }

 });
```

Then controller as follows,

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['CalculatorService']);
   {
  myApp.controller('StringController', function ($scope, StringManipulation)             

  $scope.findReverse = function () {
    $scope.reversename = StringManipulation.reverseString($scope.name);
    }
  });
```

and on the View using the controller as follows

```
      <div ng-controller="StringController">
            Enter Name:
            <input ng-model="name">
            <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="findReverse()">Reverse  
             </button>
            <div>{{reversename}}</div>
        </div>
```

I am sure missing something basic. I am getting error that

Error: error:undef
Undefined Value

any help ?

Comment: change    reverseString: function reverseString(name) to    reverseString: function(name)

Comment: function reverseString(name) to reverse(name) actually?

Comment: Hi Ben, when I tried removing function name as you suggested, Visual Studio is throwing exception !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return
 {
   reverseString: function reverseString(name)
   {
       return r(name);
   }
 }
```

[Automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi/2846298#2846298) is causing the problem. You must add the opening brace on the same line as the return statement. Otherwise the statement becomes `return;`.

```
return {
       reverseString: function reverseString(name)
       {
           return r(name);
       }
  }
```

Angular expects a return value from the factory's `$get` method. Your `StringManipulation` factory is returning `undefined` due to automatic semicolon insertion.